# What will be the result of this condition? Is it defined or compiler-dependant?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, operator-precedence

If I want to assign a new value to a variable and check if the new value is the same as the old value, I would tend to avoid using temporary variables. Could I do something like this:

```
if (oldval == (oldval = new_value()))
{
 ... do something
}
```

?
Would this behaviour be well-defined or is the evaluation priority language or compiler dependant? I could try this and see the result, but it would not guarantee that it will work on other systems as well. I am doing it in C++, so this is the language which interests me the most, but if the behaviour is consistent (or inconsistent) amongst other languages, I would like to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Code like that never gets a date to the prom.

Comment: @haccks yeah I was mistaken and deleted my comment 10s after re-thinking :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order of evaluation of the operand of `==` is not defined (I am assuming that `==` is not overloaded). It is not guaranteed whether `oldval` will evaluate first or `oldval = new_value()` will. Behavior is **undefined** in this case.

*Avoid writing such expressions that access the value of a variable and also modify that variable elsewhere in the expression*.

---

**NOTE:** Only the operators,  `,` , `&&`, `||` and `?:` guarantee that the operand evaluation takes place from left to right. So, there exist [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point):

> - Between evaluation of the left and right operands of the `&&` (logical AND), `||` (logical OR) (as part of short-circuit evaluation), and comma operators.
> - Between the evaluation of the first operand of the ternary "question-mark" operator and the second or third operand.

Comment: well I use it quite often in conditional expressions - making use of the fact, that when the value of the expression is known, the evaluation stops.
Example:  
`if (x || y)`
...
- If x is true, than y is not evaluated. This is useful for stuff like this:  
`if (x == nullptr || !x->valid())`

Comment: I don't think it is UB is `operator==` is a user defined overload.

Comment: Only the operators like `,`, `&&`, `||` and `?:` guarantee that the operand evaluation takes place from left to right.

Comment: @MatoušVrba But that's a different thing. The `||` operator is specified to evaluate left-to-right (and short-circuit).

Comment: The undefined behaviour thing. I already commented on it. I think you should clarify that.

Comment: @juanchopanza; I haven't considered the overloading case. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's better, but the order of evaluation is unspecified in all cases. It is just not UB if the operator is overloaded. It is an *unspecified* vs. *undefined* thing.

Answer (score 6):

This would be **undefined behaviour** because the write to `oldval` that occurs in `oldval = new_value()` is unsequenced with respect to a value computation that uses the value of `oldval` (*i.e.* the evaluation of the left-hand side of `==`).

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't there be a sequence point if there was an overloaded `operator==` for the types involved?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I suppose you are right. In that case we would get `operator==(oldval, oldval = new_value())` which looks to be well-defined.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't think so. While it guarantees that both `oldval` and `oldval = new_value()` will finish evaluating before `operator==` begins, the order of evaluating the two parameters to `operator==` doesn't appear to be defined. (But I'm reading Wikipedia not a standard.)

Comment: @MichaelUrman If `operator==` takes its arguments by reference then there is no value computation associated with passing the first argument; any value computations would take place in the body of `operator==` and therefore be sequenced after the modification. I believe if `operator==` takes its arguments by *value* then it's still undefined. (But I'm not 100% sure whether initialization of parameters is unsequenced w.r.t. evaluation of arguments.)

Comment: Good point on taking a reference meaning the function-call sequence point effectively defines a visible order. However, if safe, ironically that case it makes it appear like the assignment happens before the non-assignment in all cases rather than as a matter of which parameter it is.

Comment: @MichaelUrman If the two operand evaluations are sequenced, it is not undefined behaviour, even if the order of evaluation is unspecified.

Comment: @juanchopanza But that's just it; if wikipedia and my reading of it are correct, the evaluation of the two operands are *not* sequenced. Brian's point that, if passed by reference, they are as good as sequenced has merit (`&oldval` doesn't change, after all), but doesn't change whether they're sequenced.